# How did Thanos get the soul stone in What-If...?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones, thanos, marvel-what-if-2021

Spoilers for the plot of *What if..?* episode 8

In the 8th episode of *what if...?* (What if Ultron won), Thanos comes to earth with all the infinity stones except for the mind stone. Vision then kills Thanos and gets all the rest of the infinity stones.

But how did Thanos get the soul stone? In a later scene in the episode, we see Ultron conquering the universe and he gets to the Sovereign. We see there the guardians of the galaxy (including Gamora) fighting his androids.

[image]

So A: How did Thanos know where the stone is? In the movies, he gets Gamora to tell him where the stone is. How does he get the information this time? And B: who did Thanos sacrifice to get the soul stone if Gamora is alive? I don't think there is anyone else he loves or any other way he could've done it.

Comment: Not official: Gamora is likely not the only person in universe who knew about Vormir. Maybe Vormir ran tourism ads like those “Come to Jamaica” type of ads and Thanos vacationed there.

Comment: "I don't think there is anyone else he loves" — major smackdown on [Ebony Maw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebony_Maw) right there.

Comment: @SillybutTrue Even if Thanos did know about Vormir, how did he get the stone without Gamora?

Comment: Won a game of Pong against the Red Skull?

Comment: Technically, Red Skull says "In order to take the stone you must lose that which you love.", not "In order to take the stone you must lose *whom* you love."

Answer (score 4):

### We don't have an answer to this.

However, **for the sake of the plotline, Thanos *had* to get the other five Infinity Stones - *especially* the Soul Stone.** Ultron is an artificial intelligence, and though he is very sentient (enough to discover the Watcher with the help of all six Infinity Stones), he seems to feel no compassion or love for anything. Therefore, a **living being** had to get the Stone somehow, and because Thanos was already collecting Infinity Stones, it probably made most sense to the writers of the show to give him the Soul Stone. Alternatively, he could have sacrificed Nebula (his other daughter), or (my personal favorite) his chair, to get the Soul Stone.